# how to setup WordNet on red hat openshift

Tags: installation, openshift, wordnet

I need to access a WordNet db to enable synonym search in my application that I'm hosting on OpenShift by Red Hat. How can I install it on Openshift?

Answer (score 0):

You could try downloading the WordNet files to your `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` and then try installing it locally inside that directory.

1. ssh into your gear with `rhc ssh <appname`
2. cd into your `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`
3. then wget the files `wget http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/3.0/WordNet-3.0.tar.bz2`
4. untar them `tar -xvf WordNet-3.0.tar.bz2`
5. Try to install.

Note: I've never tried to install it myself but due to the way OpenShift is configured you may have trouble standing this up in the same gear as your web application. Therefore I would recommend creating a Openshift DIY application and then doing the steps above.

Comment: thx for the comment, I will give it a try and keep you posted!